# How can I get T-SQL PRINT statements to come up in SQL Server Profiler Traces?

Tags: t-sql, debugging, trace

I'm not very experienced with SQL Server Profiler (2005, 2008).  I'd like to print some info to a trace from a stored procedure.  PRINT statements don't seem to output to my trace.  How can I easily get the PRINT statements to output to the trace?

If that's not what trace (or PRINT) is really meant for, what's a quick easy alternative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use sp_trace_generateevent to "fire" an event out to your SQL trace.  There's an example of it on the BOL page for the proc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx

Comment: I could not find the example referenced, but here is a more recent one https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fort_sql/2012/06/21/capture-custom-events-in-profiler-for-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can put a print statement into your stored procedure and execute the stored procedure in management studio (exec YourProcedure @Parameter1=10...) and on the messages tab you will see the print statement.  If the procedure is running from an application with a lot of parameters you could trace the database to get the exec statement copy it and run it in management studio to see the print statements.