# How can I write a message to SQL profiler from Sql a query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-profiler

I am troubleshooting for some SQL issue and I use SQL Profiler in order to diagnose some problem.

Is it possible to write some messages into SQL Profiler by adding some lines in a TSQL query?

thanks!

Comment: I think this question has the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501432/how-can-i-get-t-sql-print-statements-to-come-up-in-sql-server-profiler-traces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by adding comment to your t-sql
like

```
 -- My message
select * from table1
```

and send all to sql

Answer (score 0):

The Application Name should also be different.  For our installation, activity on the website gives an application name of ".Net SqlClient Data Provider", while queries from SQL Server Management Studio are designated as... well... "SQL Server Management Studio"